# Reversing black box algorithm

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, brute-force-attack

I'm trying to solve the next problem:

1. We have `X` - input vector, its length is 128 bits.
2. Output vector `Y`, its length 2048 bits. We know that `Y` has a proper value, if and only if "CRC" is valid, to calculate this "CRC" we have to know all bits of `Y` of course.
3. We have a function `F()`, which does `F(X) -> Y`. This function is a black box for us.
4. Also, it's guaranteed for us, that only one unique `X` is the solution.

What clear for me:

1. `F()` has many collisions (it is oblivious, because `size(X)` < `size(Y)`). But I don't see a clear way how to use this.
2. Brutforce is not the way, as complexity of `F()` is high. And the only way to understand that result is right, calculate "CRC"(additional complexity).

Task: find `X` which produces a proper value of `Y` with proper "CRC". In other words: I need to find X such that F(X) satisfies additional criteria ("CRC")

As I don't have any crypto analysis experience, my question is pretty simple, wherefrom I should start? I tried to google, but no luck, or maybe I googled it wrong. I have read a couple of articles about linear and differential cryptoanalysis, but seems to it is a different case.

Any advice is welcome! Not looking for the solution, but for the way how to figure out the problem.

Comment: Are you given Y and need to find an X? Or do you need to find an X such that F(X) satisfies additional criteria ("CRC")?

Comment: why do you say there are collisions if output length is longer than input length?

Comment: @AmanGrewal I need to find X such that F(X) satisfies additional criteria ("CRC")

Comment: @kodlu because I'm not a crypto expert, and seems to I used this terminology wrong.